# Ruby question mark operator, what does this mean?

Tags: ruby

this might be a very vague question. But i am wondering if someone could translate this into pseudocode:

```
a = (1 + (bool ? rand(13) : 0)
```

Does it mean that `a` will become any value between 0-13 + 1? what is the purpose of the boolean value and the question mark?

Comment: _what is the purpose of the boolean value and the question mark?_ I think it serves no purpose, unless it's replaced with a variable . Otherwise is as you mentioned, a is equals to 1 plus a random number between 0 and 12 (inclusive).

Comment: Thank you Sebastian! I'll change my post to make the question more clear.

Comment: See [ternary if](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Ternary+if)

Comment: @loopy : We don't know if the code in question contains a "boolean" value, in particular since Ruby does not have a "boolean" datatype. We only know that `bool` is some variable or parameterless method, which is (due to the ternary-if-operator) evaluated in a boolean context, i.e. is regarded as  _trueish_  or _falsy_ - the latter is the case if it has the value `false` or `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `(true ? rand(13) : 0)`  mean `(if true then rand(13) else 0 end)`

if you have directly "true" in condition, the "else" is never called (is useless), you can write : `a = 1 + rand(13)` directly ;)

2. `rand(13)` give random int between 0 and 12 ;)
   if you want "13" put  `rand(14)`
   personally I always use range like this (all range is include, it's easier to understand) : `rand(0..13)`

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed it from a boolean variable to ```true``` just to simply the question. But thank you so much for your explanation! It cleared everything up :)